# Export node.js class to be used with require()

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I am exporting the following class:

```
export default class Tester {
}
```

The problem is that when I transpile this and import it with:

```
const Tester = require('./dist/Tester');
```

The problem is that to use the Tester class I need to use it like this:

```
const example = new Tester.Tester();
```

How can I export it so I do:

```
const example = new Tester();
```

Comment: What version of node are you using?  Are you using babel on the node side to transpile, or are you using native EJS support in node?

Answer (score 1):

The weird syntax is actually caused by you using 2 different import/export dialect, es6 and commonjs. Babel transpilation enables you to use both in the same system.

In es6

- exports are written with `export`
- imports are written with `import`

Example:

```
// -- es6

// tester.js

export default class Tester {}  // default export
export const SomeConsts = {}    // named export

// main.js

import Tester, { SomeConsts } from "./tester";
```

In nodejs implementation of commonjs

- exports are written with `module.exports`
- imports are written with `require()`

Example:

```
// -- commonjs

// tester.js

class Tester {}
const SomeConsts = {}

module.exports = { Tester, SomeConsts }  // arbitrary export

// main.js

const TesterModule = require("./tester.js");
const Tester = TesterModule.Tester;
const SomeConsts = TesterModule.SomeConsts;

// --or--

const { Tester, SomeConsts } = require("./tester.js");
```

**Edit** :

If you want `Tester` class to be the root of the export and still want to export `SomeConsts`, you'll have to make `SomeConsts` a part of `Tester` class.

```
// -- commonjs

// tester.js
class Tester {
  static SomeConsts = {}
}

module.exports = {}

// main.js

const Tester = require("./tester.js")
const TesterInstance = new Tester():
```

Comment: I see, but let's assume I have a index.js file that exports Tester and SomeConsts. Is there a way to make Tester the "default" export so when I require it I can do const TesterModule = require("./tester.js");  const x = new TesterModule();

Comment: @johnnyshrewd
You can only export 1 root object in module.exports.
If you want to preserve SomeConsts you'll have to make it part of Tester.
```
// tester.js

class Tester{
   static SomeConsts = {}
}
module.exports = Tester

// main.js

const Tester =  require("./tester.js")
const TesterInstance = new Tester()

```

Answer (score 0):

You could try amend the import block to use object destructuring:

```js
const { Tester } = require('./dist/Tester');
```